# OverlappingFileLockException while logging

Tags: java, exception, logging

When I launch jar file on local machine, there are created two log files written by two loggers confugured slf4j in the same directory. Everything ok in the previous case. Two files is created. But when I launch from my computer this jar through filemanager (TotalCmd, FAR) on network drive there is java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException. Just one first file has been created in the folder on network drive.

```
package mypackage;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
import ru.mycompany.bicomp.app.BaseApp;
import ru.mycompany.db.client.TaskContext;
import ru.mycompany.form.error.JInvErrorService;
import ru.mycompany.jinvecd.impl.ECDAppImpl;


public class ECDApp extends BaseApp {

    private static final ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ecd");
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("EcdAppLogger");

    @Override
    public String getAppID() {
        return "XXI.JECD";
    }

    @Override
    protected void initialize(String[] args) {
        super.initialize(args); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        configureLoggerOfApplication();
    }

    protected String createLoggerFileName() {

        return "logs\\" + "ECDAppRootLog." + getAppID() + ".log";
    }

    private void configureLoggerOfApplication() {
        try {
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(createLoggerFileName(), true);
            fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
            ch.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            ch.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            logger.addHandler(ch);
            logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            logger.info("------------------------Start " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "----------------------");
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            JInvErrorService.handleException(null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Exception begin to throw from

> FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(createLoggerFileName(), true);

Folder logs\ is existed, cause it was created by configurations of first logger

```
protected String createDefaultLoggerFileName() {

    try {
        Path p = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".", "logs");
        Files.createDirectory(p);
        //Files.createDirectory((""));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }

    return "logs\\" + getAppID() + ".log";
}

/**
 *
 */
protected void configureDefaultLogger() throws IOException {

    FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(createDefaultLoggerFileName());

    fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    Logger defaultLogger = Logger.getLogger("ru.mycompany." + getAppID());

    defaultLogger.addHandler(fh);

    appLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ru.mycompany." + getAppID());

    logSystemProperties();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Actually there's not even a question.

Answer (score 1):

This issue filed under [JDK-8031438:](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031438) FileHandler throws OverlappingFileLockException.  Even though that is not marked as fixed the patch for [JDK-8048020](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048020): Regression on java.util.logging.FileHandler should resolve the issue.  That was fixed in JDK8u40.

The FileHandler documentation doesn't declare that OverlappingFileLockException can be thrown from the constructor.  Reading the [FileChannel.tryLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock%28%29) documentation it appears that failure to acquire a lock can be indicated by returning null or throwing an OverlappingFileLockException.  The FileHandler.openFiles method doesn't seem to handle the case of OverlappingFileLockException being thrown since it extends IllegalStateException.  The fact that this is thrown from the FileHandler indicates that this is a bug.

Having said that, from the NIO [FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) documentation, "In general, great care should be taken when locking files that reside on network filesystems."  So even if this bug is fixed it still may not be possible to what you are trying to do per contract of the Java API.